# Kashering a stove

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, kashering-kosherization, appliances

The common custom I have noticed is for people to use the same stove top for meat and dairy. However, people also claim you need to kasher a stove top before use. How are these two positions not contradictory?

Comment: @msh210 possible dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/568/759 Or dupable with some choice edits?

Comment: @DoubleAA that question — and its answers! — are _Pesach_-specific. This is about a new stove.

Comment: Other than Pesach, I am not aware of people ***requiring*** a full kashering of the stove top before use.