# Does a pot that cooked food with a bug in it need to be kashered afterward?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, bugs

If one were cooking a pot of pasta or a soup and later found a bug or many bugs in the pasta or soup, would the pot need to be re-kashered after it was thoroughly cleaned?

Comment: As my teacher said, the pot is Kosher but the bug is still treif.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No need to kasher once the bugs have been cleaned out, because the halachah is that bugs are נותן טעם לפגם, they impart an unpleasant taste [that does not enhance the flavor of other foods].  Source: [Yoreh Deah siman 104](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.104.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Comment: And the Gemara at the end of Gittin says that if you find a fly in your soup, the appropriate thing to do is pull out the fly and eat the soup.

Comment: @shalom - but it's not necessarily referring to *hot* soup. And anyway, a fly would usually not be large enough to prohibit an entire bowl of soup.

Comment: @Dave re "not be large enough", wouldn't a _b'ria_ ("_berya_") be large enough no matter how much soup? Or (very likely) am I confusing my concepts?

Comment: @msh210, if the berya is whole, you'll have a problem. Once you pull it out, all that remains is bug juice, which isn't a berya. Berya would only present problems if it's a thick, opaque stew in which you think you're likely to unwittingly eat a whole bug while eating the soup.

Comment: Would edible but non-kosher bugs be considered נותן טעם לפגם?

Comment: @Shalom The concept of berya brings up fond memories: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/213/why-would-a-product-be-only-for-cooking-and-pureeing (Note the link in the first comment on the question.)

Comment: Isaac, we generally treat all bugs as *ta'am lifgam.* As one teacher of mine said, when you actually consider how many species of insect are theoretically edible, this may be a case of halacha giving us a nice break.

Comment: @IsaacMoses The Shulchan Aruch says this applies toדברים המאוסים שנפשו של אדם קצה בהם כנמלים וזבובים ויתושים, but there is some dispute as to what kinds of bugs are included in this category of "repulsive to people." See, for example, the [third paragraph here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=1712&rid=4739).

Comment: The last time I tasted a bug was in summer camp when they served "bug juice." It was pretty awful, admittedly. I'll have to remember this answer next time the waiter refuses to remove the fly from my soup.

Answer (score 4):

Your average bug is probably not much bigger than a half a centimeter. That means its volume is 0.125 cm^3. Assuming a bug is roughly the same density as water, a bug should weigh around 125mg. 60 times the weight of a bug would be roughly 7.5 grams. Most pots contain more food then that.

I did it in weight because it is easier to appreciate weight measurements, it would come to roughly the same result if one calculated in volume, a pot 60 times .125 cm^3 would be 7.5 cm^3. That is definitely smaller than your average pot.

In other words, there is a good chance that the bug would be batul in the pot.

Comment: Isn't _shishim_ by volume only, though?