# Dead Fly on Hot Oily Pan

Tags: halacha, food, kashrut-kosher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a pot that cooked food with a bug in it need to be kashered afterward?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10560/does-a-pot-that-cooked-food-with-a-bug-in-it-need-to-be-kashered-afterward)

Fly lands on hot oily pan and duly dies. Kashrut implications? (Of the pan, not the fly :p )

Comment: It depends: Did it do the backstroke first?

Comment: nosen taam lifgam.  Get rid of the fly and it's all good.

Comment: @YDK Probably batel beshishim against the mass of the frying pan too.

Comment: dupe: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10560/759

Comment: @DoubleAA But not over the volume of the oil. Does the pan mass really count for the 60?

Comment: *mass* of the pan or *volume* of the pan?  If mass, I suggest we all start using cast iron...

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Touchee! But why not [Osmium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmium)?

Comment: @DoubleAA, how much oil would be needed to be able to include the volume of the pan?

Comment: @DoubleAA really? Read the sections on [Precautions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmium#Precautions) and [Price](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmium#Price) not to mention the smell or its effects on fats, "As a strong oxidant, it cross-links lipids mainly by reacting with unsaturated carbon-carbon bonds, and thereby both fixes biological membranes in place in tissue samples and simultaneously stains them."

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman שומר מצוה לא ידע דבר רע :-)

Comment: @DoubleAA well played :)

Comment: 60 is calculated by volume and the pan doesn't count.  I can find sources if I need to, but I am quite sure here.  Sixty based on volume is from a AskOU session.