# Do I have to check my fruits and vegetables [for insects] before I put them in a smoothie?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, bugs, fruits, inspection, vegetables

I use both frozen and fresh fruits and vegetables in my smoothies, and mostly organic. Does the type of fruit or vegetable matter? For example, produce that generally has more insects, such as raspberries or strawberries? I use kale, spinach, raspberries, strawberries, and more.

Comment: To focus the question: would blending such fruits be considered "mevatel issur le-chatchillah," which is not permitted.

Comment: Crushing a berya should be prohibited. It's exactly the case of the Gemara: egozim v'nesparzu. See YD 99.  (I didn't make this an answer because I am not sure and have no seforim in front if me)

Comment: also relevant: http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/Issue10.pdf and http://www.kosherveyosher.com/insects.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should CYLOR for a final ruling, but it seems (Shach and Taz to [YD 84:13](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4204), Chochmat Adam [52:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33594&st=&pgnum=151), see also Rama [OC 553:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=96) (however see Shu"t R Akiva Eiger 76)) there should be no problem blending the fruit as the intention is to prepare the food not to nullify the insects. Once the insects are cut up, they are nullified in the mixture (YD 101:6).

Additionally, if it is not a majority of that kind of fruit that is infested with bugs, but rather just a significant minority (*miut hamatzui*) have bugs, then it is possible that there is no problem nullifying it as it is only a doubtful prohibition (Terumat HaDeshen 171, Shach YD 92 sk 8).

Comment: Boy do I feel sheepish. +1

Comment: Siman 104 seems relevant here as well. See Taz who argues with the Rama there, if it is _nikar_, because of _din chetzi shiur_. The Nekudat Hakesef and the Shach defend the Rama, because if you can't separate it, it has the din of _lach b'lach_. Sefardim hold by the Taz (Kaf Hachaim 5)

Answer (score 1):

If it is known that these fruits and vegetables contain bugs one has to check them.To go ahead and blend it up and now the bugs are not whole that is assur because of the din assur mevatel issur lchatchilah.However if it was done bshogeg I believe it is mutar.There are some fruit which people won't eat because of bugs and even washing doesn't help and if someone who holds it can be cleaned and checked blended it already then one can partake in it .

when it comes to which fruit or vegetables need to be checked and clean one should ask his posek or hasgacha he holds of which ones need checking or not.

http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94

Comment: What do you mean "known"? If it is known then you have to remove the bugs, not just check for them...

Comment: It is obvious what I meant when I wrote check it means take them out,the whole question is concerning the bugs!

Comment: I don't know if you are talking about fruits which for sure have bugs or might have bugs. There are different kinds and it can make a difference.

Comment: The halacha is the same one has to check and remove them if it for sure  has or likely has bugs!

Comment: If it's just a miut hamatzui then you have a chiyuv bedika miderabanan. That's different than a vadai issur deoraita. It's not even clear the former is currently a cheftza shel issur, as opposed to just having a chiyuv bedika. Plus you haven't even addressed why this is mevatel issur if you are just trying to make it into a liquid.

Comment: I am addressing if it is commonly found and one for sure has to check,because there is a major machlokes on many fruits and vegetables which need checking or if it is a miut or not,the question is really two questions and the answer depends on which posek you hold of,I answered the question in a way which I believe is not disputed.

Comment: There is no second question. Just answer what is the din for things which are miut hamatzui and what is the din for things that are rov/vadai. You don't need to deal with which fruits are which. You haven't justified why a miut hamatzui makes a cheftza shel issur that ein mevatlin should apply. You haven't even justified why ein mevatlin applies at all since no one is trying to mevatel anything!!