# Modern bug checking sources

Tags: sources-mekorot, bugs, responsa

Where are modern she'elot and tshuvot that deal with circumstances surrounding bug checking?

Looking for sources that talk about things like freezing and blending.

Where can I find such things?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35147/759

Comment: I saw that (should have linked) but I would imagine this is also a question of how blended it would have to be (maybe if there was even one bug that was left unblended it would not be possible to be mevatel?). Is the freezing issue discussed anywhere on this site?

Comment: www.stark-k.org

Comment: I'm not looking for a practical answer to anything, I'm looking for the first time (or a canonical time) these questions were asked and answered in written form, along with sources