# Can chewing food very well eliminate the issue of eating bugs?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, eating, bugs

If the prohibition of eating prohibited foods does not take place until it passes ones throat (Hanaat Grono), would chewing fruits and vegetables (that have a bug concern) very well be enough to remove the issue of eating bugs?

Comment: Are teeth fine enough to damage the really small bugs? Are you asking for the Metziut or if this would be halachically permissible?

Comment: Tasting Issurim can be problematic too.

Comment: Bitul Isur lechathilla is prohibited

Comment: This is not nullifying lechathila, as you don't even know if there's a bug in it

Comment: Yishaq Also because you aren't intending to crush the bugs to nullify them (well, I guess depending how hard you purposefully chew). @kouty

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35147/759

Comment: You are assuming the concept of berya was predicated on swallowing said berya whole?

Comment: Do you have a source that disagrees with the presumption?